# magento Google Sitemap defaults to incorrect url

Tags: php, magento

I have a multi domain magento 1.9.0.1 installation setup and I'm trying to get the google sitemaps generating properly.. Trouble is two of the domains are generating the path prefix with the secure URL rather than the unsecure URL. I can't understand why this is?

Is there some option that affects what the prefix is https:// or http://  I need it to use the unsecured path and there seems no reason to why it is not using it.

Answer (score 0):

my fault seems like they all use the secure url but I had a different one setup for the 1 domain.. changing to unsecure url was solution..